# How to link hero image in css for flask application

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add a hero image on my flask app page. Following is the directory structure for my flask project.

```
-static
 |--css_files
   |--my.css
 |--images
   |--img.jpg
-templates
 |--layout.html
```

Now, in order to add a hero image, I have following `HTML` code in `layout.html`-

```
<div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>My Heading</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To add style, I am using following `CSS` code in `my.css`-

```
.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url({{ url_for('static',filename='images/img.jpg') }});
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 50%;
    /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

But, I am only able to see the `hero-text` and not the image.
How can I link this `img.jpg` into `my.css`?

I tried absolute path also,`backgrouond: url('/static/images/img.jpg')` but didn't work.

Comment: have you included the css in the html.. ?

Comment: @SarthakNegi yes

Comment: check the console, is it giving any error like wasn't able to find the jpeg

Comment: In the console it shows `127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2018 16:30:40] "GET /static/images/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -` but I am not able to see the image

Comment: you can try two things..first do an inline style and then check..another would be to change the .jpg into .jpeg and then see

Comment: @SumedhJunghare have you solved your problem. I am facing same..

Answer (score 2):

Change the url like this

```
background:url('../static/images/img.jpg') ;
```

Comment: not working for me. I am trying like this: background: url("../static/hero-bg.png") top center;

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to replace the absolute path part with the url_for function, like this:

```
background:url({{ url_for('static', filename='images/img.jpg') }})
```

The function converts it into the absolute path for you.

Answer (score 0):

**A quickguide to paths**

There is three ways to get to your file. Each one depends on the location of your file and your calling point (your html-file).

> Abbr: Folder Containing File = FCF. Calling Point (html-file) = CP

```
url('pathtofile/file.jpg') /* FCF is located in the same folder as your CP


url('../pathtofile/file.jpg') /* FCF is located in a folder containing the folder to your CP. Your path goes ONE step backwards and then forward.


url('/pathtofile/file.jpg') /* This starts the search in the absolute root-folder
```

You can use both `url('../pathtofile/file.jpg')` and `url('/pathtofile/file.jpg')` for your setup.